# DAG's task initialization takes time

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

We have a composer environment which has below configuration details.

- Composer Version:  composer-1.10.0-airflow-1.10.6
- Machine Type : n1-standard-4
- Disk size (GB): 100
- Worker Nodes: 6
- python version:3
- worker_concurrency: 32
- parallelism:128

We have a problem in DAG to initialize it's task and it is taking more time. For example DAG has 3 tasks like Task1 -> Task2 -> Task3. Task1 initializes taking time (minimum 5 mins) and once initialized completion time of that task within seconds. Task2 initialized taking again 5 mins and executed within seconds. Like that task's initialization is taking time but completion of that task is quickly done. Have scheduled this DAG every 5 mins, but completing this DAG takes around 10 mins at least. So affecting functionalities and execution of the process.

Here are the functionalities of each three tasks. Task1 objective is to gather the basic information such as storage location from configuration files/variables. Task2 checks the storage whether any new files are coming and based on the file triggers the relevant DAGs. Task3 objective is to send success email.

Also, I noted that worker nodes did not splitted the work among themselves. Always one worker node's CPU utilization is high compared to other worker nodes. Do not know what could be the reason for it. One more interesting is even though the other DAG's are not running at that time this DAG still takes 10 mins to execute.

Appreciated your help in solving this case.

Comment: Did you observe Pod evictions for any of workloads especially `airflow-worker` and `airflow-scheduler` that could be affected under high CPU pressure on this particular GKE node?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I don't have the reputation required.

My initial advice is to [upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading#version-selection) your Composer version, 1.10.0 has a few known bugs that are fixed in later versions. Right now the latest version is 1.10.4. This should correct the CPU that stays at 100% (it did in our case). Are there many other DAGs running on your instance?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, we have around 150+ DAGs based on this particular DAG initialization(Task2 functionality). We will upgrade the latest version of the Composer in my project, meanwhile please let me know if you have any other ideas to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment the reason behind the high CPU pressure on the particular GKE node might be more evident after the troubleshooting performed on [*Airflow workflow*](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags)/[GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#workload_issues) sides.

It is happening regularly that on some Aiflow runtime node the computation resources (*Memory/CPU*) are running out of the node capacity causing *Airflow workloads(Pods)* being [Evicted](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/) and further restarted loosing all the process states data, however [Celery executor](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/) which is responsible for assigning tasks to the Airflow workers can even be not aware about inconvenient state/*time-out* of the worker and doesn't keep the certain action to re-assign this task to another worker.

According to GCP Composer [*release notes*](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#April_27_2020), the vendor has provided some essential fixes in the latest `composer-1.10.*` patches, improving Composer runtime performance and reability, as @parakeet said in his answer.

You can also refer to this GCP Composer [known issues](https://sites.google.com/corp/google.com/composer/known-issues) knowledge base to keep track of the current problems and workarounds that vendor shares to the community.